# how to convert ldap to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, ldap

does pandas have a native way of dealing with ldapsearch results?

given the code

```py
l_rhds = ldap.initialize('ldap://%s' % conf['server'])
l_rhds.protocol_version = ldap.VERSION3
l_rhds.set_option(ldap.OPT_NETWORK_TIMEOUT, 5)
l_rhds.simple_bind_s(conf['user'], conf['pass'])

ldapsearch = l_rhds.search_s(conf['basedn'], ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, searchFilter, retrieveAttributes)
```

which returns

```
[
    ('uid=aaa,ou=myou', {'mail': ['aaa@mail'], 'jid': ['837cefc3-88b66f05']}),
    ('uid=bbb,ou=myou', {'mail': ['bbb@mail'], 'jid': ['9f36f888-aa4ef8ef']})
]
```

and converted to a pandas dataframe with `dfLdap = pd.DataFrame(ldapData)` becomes

```
                  0                                                        1
0   uid=aaa,ou=myou  {u'mail': [u'aaa@mail'], u'jid': [u'837cefc3-88b66f05']
1   uid=bbb,ou=myou  {u'mail': [u'bbb@mail'], u'jid': [u'9f36f888-aa4ef8ef']
```

how could i get a dataframe similiar to

```
                 dn      mail                 jid
0   uid=aaa,ou=myou  aaa@mail   837cefc3-88b66f05
1   uid=bbb,ou=myou  bbb@mail   9f36f888-aa4ef8ef
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a native pandas function for doing this but the following should work :

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{
  'dn': dn,
  'mail': attr.get('mail', [''])[0],
  'jid': attr.get('jid', [''])[0],
  } for dn, attr in ldapsearch
])
```

Also you might need to use `attr.get(...)[0].decode('utf8')` to convert the attribute values (if binary string `b''`).